# How Extract the http code, size header and title from website in bash?

Tags: bash, curl, grep

With curl I'm extracting the %{http_code} %{size_header} %{redirect_url} and it works great but, I also like to add the website title to the Bash response.

```
usage: check-website.sh website-list.txt

#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
while read LINE; do
  curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -i -s -k -o /dev/null --silent --max-time 2 --write-out '%{http_code} %{size_header} %{redirect_url}' "$LINE"
  echo " $LINE"
done < ${FILE}
```

I was looking on extracting the titles with this curl command:

```
curl -s example.com | grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | cut -d'>' -f2-
```

but I'm not sure on how to do this, in order to get the bash output like:

```
%{http_code} %{size_header} %{redirect_url} $website_title
```

Can anyone help me to join the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of redirecting to `/dev/null` you can redirect to your `grep` command. Note that you should use the case insensitive grep option. I also added an extra space at the end of your `--write-out`:

```
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -i -s -k -o >(grep -io "<title>[^<]*" | cut -d'>' -f2-) --silent --max-time 2 --write-out '%{http_code} %{size_header} %{redirect_url} ' "$LINE"
```